# jQuery if div content starts with <strong> tag the do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

How can I detect if a div starts with a strong tag and add a class to the parent div? For Example, I need to style the output of the results of this autocomplete https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

which would then give the following code:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999; top: 322px; left: 512.328px; width: 383px; display: none;">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0"><strong>H</strong>airdressers</div>
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="1">C<strong>h</strong>artered Surveyor</div>
</div>
```

Where the div has the  tag I would like to add a class to it to then style in CSS for divs that only start with the strong tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the first child of an element using jquery's `contents()` method. You can then check what type of element it is, before adding the class to the parent element if needed, something like this:

```js
$('.autocomplete-suggestion').each(function() {
  var firstChild = $(this).contents()[0];
  if ($(firstChild).is('strong')) {
    $(this).addClass('foo');
  }
});
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions">
  <div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0"><strong>H</strong>airdressers</div>
  <div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="1">C<strong>h</strong>artered Surveyor</div>
</div>
```